# How to get stock quantity for a given product_id

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, stock

Does anyone know how to get StockItem by product_id in Magento 2.4.x? We have the following code that works most of the time, but sometimes it throws the following error: "The stock item with the "12399" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again."

```
class AbstractTemplate extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

 protected $_stockItemRepository;

 public function __construct(

     \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository, 
             array $data = array()
 ) {

     $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;

   }

 public function getStockItem($productId)
     {
     return $this->_stockItemRepository->get($productId);
 }
}
```

then we do:

```
$product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($item->getId());
$stock_quantity = $this->getStockItem($item->getId());

$product_quantity = $this->or_else($stock_quantity->getQty(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **StockRegistryInterface** Like this:

> Code with dependency Indection:

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_stockRegistryInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistryInterface, 
        array $data = array()
    ) {

        $this->_stockRegistryInterface = $stockRegistryInterface;
    }

    public function getStockItem($productId)
    {
        return $this->_stockRegistryInterface->getStockItem($productId);
    }
}
```

> For testing, you can check with objectmanager:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$stockRegistry = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
$stockItem=$stockRegistry->getStockItem($_product->getId());
```

**Note: Must use code with dependency Injection.**

Comment: No, can't use this. StockRegistryInterface has been deprecated in Magento 2.4